# Junos syslog filter Cron facility

Tags: juniper-junos, syslog

Is there a way in Junos 12.3R4.6 to filter Cron jobs out of the syslog that is being sent to a host running Kiwi. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, log filtering is done on syslog servers, not on routers, but if you really want to do this on your router, it's possible.

A very simple way to achieve it is to set your log level higher than `informational`, but that filters out more than just cron messages, so that probably isn't such a good idea.

But there's a nice KB article on how to filter syslog output: [KB9382](http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB9382), so probably something like this should work:

```
[edit system syslog]
host 192.0.2.1 {
  any any;
  match "!(.*cron.*)";
}
```

Comment: Great thank you I will give this a try and report back.